# JSP get the name of the uploaded file

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, blob

I need to upload a Blob file into a MySQL database using JSP. I was able to do that, but I just can't store the name of the actual file. It's very important because the next step would be a list of the uploaded files. This is what I got so far:

```
@MultipartConfig
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        DBConnection DBC = new DBConnection();
// this is the database connection method
        Connection con = DBC.connection();

        InputStream inputFile = null;
        Part file = request.getPart("file");
        if(file != null){
            inputFile = file.getInputStream();
        }
        Date utilDate = new Date();
        Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());

        try{
            String fileUpload = "insert into uploads(file,uploaded_date) values('"+inputFile+"','"+sqlDate+"')";
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            int insertFile = st.executeUpdate(fileUpload);
            response.sendRedirect("ok.jsp");
        }catch(SQLException e){

        }
    }
```

So, if I upload a file called picture.jpg, I'd like to store picture.jpg in a String, not the streams java.io.FileInputStream@55c3ece1 or something like this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Java EE Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html) it is possible to retrieve the file name from *Content-Disposition* Header. The linked article shows how to do exactly that.